# Why if I does not handle the result from fetch api correctly, then fetch goes into error. using redux-thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I get data: `[{name: "s"}]` across fetch api. The fetch action goes very well. But I did not handle the data correctly  in the component App at this line `return <p key={index}>{item}</p>`.I know I should replace `{item}` by `{item.name}`. But I don't understand if I use `{item}` in the uncorrect way, why the fetch action goes into error?

this is my code. and the log result is `[Object]` and `-------error-----`

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';

const actions = {
    search: params => (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(actions.beginSearch());
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/search",{
            method: 'POST',
            data:  {},
            credentials: true,
        }).then((res) => {
            return res.json()
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data)//res.data = [{name: "s"}];
            dispatch(actions.doneSearch(res.data));
        }).catch(() => {
            console.log('-------error-----');
            // dispatch(actions.failSearch("error"));
        });
    },
    beginSearch: () => ({
        type: 'BEGIN_SEARCH',
    }),
    doneSearch: data => ({
        type: 'DONE_SEARCH',
        payload: data,
    }),
    failSearch: err => ({
        type: 'FAIL_SEARCH',
        payload: err,
    }),
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {dispatch, listdata} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    listdata.map((item,index) => {
                        return <p key={index}>{item}</p>
                    })
                }
                <button onClick={()=>{
                    dispatch(actions.search())
                }}>click to get data...</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        listdata: state,
    };
}

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
const reducers = (state=[], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "DONE_SEARCH":
            return [...action.payload]
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware) );

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Container />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('container'),
);
```

thx for your help~

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dispatching your action inside your second `then`, that's where the error bubbles up to, when it eventually errors all the way down in your render function. Then the following `catch` catches it.

Remember when you have a chain of functions, the error will bubble all the way up the chain until something catches it or your UI explodes.

Comment: Thx for your answer. But I can not understand it very well. Is there any standard document referred this?